# How to fix link error when rebuild OpenCV 4.5.1

Tags: opencv

I try to rebuild opencv 4.5.1 with opencv-contrib-master but get lots of link error.
Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Please try to share error and code snippets instead of their ss

Comment: I just rebuild opencv 4.5.1 source with opencv-contrib-master. So there is no code snippets. This error is VS2019 can not generate opencv dll, but lib is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out that opencv-contrib-master ca not build with Qt been selected